# Must StartNewAsync be awaited on the orchestration client?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have an Azure orchestration where the orchestration client, which triggers the orchestration, threw a timeout exception.

The orchestration client function only does two things, starting two orchestrations, awaiting each as most example code suggest to.

```
await orchestrationClient.StartNewAsync("TableOrchestrator", updates);
await orchestrationClient.StartNewAsync("ClientOrchestrator", clientExport);
```

However, as I understand then the orchestration client is not a special function like the orchestration functions, so it can only run for a max of 10 minutes. 
Obviously there is a high chance that the combined run time of my two orchestrations exceeds 10 minutes in total.

**Questions:**

1. Is the orchestration client state saved like the actual orchestration functions?
2. Do I need to await the orchestrations they do not depend on previous orchestration results?

**Update** Made a complete example of what my code does, and the runtimes as shown below.

It seems that starting an orchestration will await it if there is code written after, but not if the orchestration is the last statement!

**Updated Questions:**

1. Will any code after calling StartNewAsync() make the function await till the orchestration really finishes? or will e.g. log statements not trigger this behaviour?
2. Is it the recommended code practice that StartNewAsync() should only be called after all other code has executed?

.

```
public static class testOrchestration
{
    [FunctionName("Start")]
    public static async Task Start([TimerTrigger("0 */30 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true, UseMonitor = false)]TimerInfo myStartTimer, [OrchestrationClient] DurableOrchestrationClient orchestrationClient, ILogger log)
    {
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        log.LogInformation(new EventId(0, "Startup"), "Starting Orchestror 1 ***");

        await orchestrationClient.StartNewAsync("Orchestrator", "ONE");
        log.LogInformation($"Elapsed time, await ONE: {DateTime.Now - startTime}");

        await Task.Delay(5000);
        log.LogInformation($"Elapsed time, await Delay: {DateTime.Now - startTime}");

        log.LogInformation(new EventId(0, "Startup"), "Starting Orchestror 2 ***");
        await orchestrationClient.StartNewAsync("Orchestrator", "TWO");
        log.LogInformation($"Elapsed time, await TWO: {DateTime.Now - startTime}");
    }


    [FunctionName("Orchestrator")]
    public static async Task<string> TestOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContextBase context, ILogger log)
    {
        var input = context.GetInput<string>();
        log.LogInformation($"Running {input}");
        await Task.Delay(5000);

        return $"Done {input}";
    }
}
```

Running this gives me the following output:

```
Starting Orchestror 1 ***
Elapsed time, await ONE: 00:00:08.5445755
Running ONE
Elapsed time, await Delay: 00:00:13.5541264
Starting Orchestror 2 ***
Elapsed time, await TWO: 00:00:13.6211995
Running TWO
```

Comment: See my answer for 2). For 1) I'm not sure what you mean. please clarify

Answer (score 6):

`StartNewAsync()` just schedules the orchestrators to be started (immediately). To await those calls does not mean that your initial function will really wait for the orchestrators to run - or even to actually start and finish its work.

> The StartNewAsync (.NET) or startNew (JavaScript) method on the
>   orchestration client binding starts a new instance. Internally, this
>   method enqueues a message into the control queue, which then triggers
>   the start of a function with the specified name that uses the
>   orchestration trigger binding.
>
> **This async operation completes when the orchestration process is
>   successfully scheduled**

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-instance-management?tabs=csharp#start-instances)

This async operation completes when the orchestration process is successfully scheduled.

So yes: You should await those calls (can also be done in parallel as Miguel suggested). But it will not take longer than a few milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I am a bit confused about your claim that the calls are not really await though! With my code currently awaiting the StartNewAsync() calls I can clearly see that my first orchestration will run to completion before my second one starts.

Comment: That might have various reasons but it should not be visible in your starter function. Just add a log before and after StartNewAsync and look at the times. You can also - just for the sake of testing, add a Timer (=delay) of, lets say 30 seconds, in your first orchestrator

Comment: I added the quote above

Comment: I actually cannot find a code example starting more than one orchestration.. I remembered wrong.
However, I do have some trivial code in between the two orchestration calls, 2 log statements and a for loop, and I can visually see that this code does not run until the first orchestration completes. I think the key phrase from your source is "successfully scheduled" which I am now guessing does not happen until previous code or orchestrations have run.

Comment: This still leaves me unable to understand in what cases my orchestration client might end up timing out, and in what scenarios everything will simply be scheduled.

Comment: Your starter function should really not time out when only starting orchestrators. If that happens, there is something wrong in the runtime. Can you maybe add the code of your two orchestrators?

Comment: I cannot really post any meaningful part of the orchestration here, but I know for a fact that the first one takes minimum 1 min, max 5 minutes. For the other one it can max take 18 minutes, cause I will kill the orchestration if it schedules an activity that would take it beyond that runtime. So in total I never expect more than 20 something minutes of runtime

Comment: why dont you start the second orchestrator as the last thing your first orchestrator does? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-sub-orchestrations?tabs=csharp

Comment: I could do a suborchestration, it would just not make the code as nice to read.

Comment: I have updated my question with a full example and followup questions. Honestly now I am more confused since it seems the behaviour of awaiting StartNewAsync() is not consistent!

Answer (score 0):

If they don't depend on each other, you can run them in parallel using:

```
var t1 = orchestrationClient.StartNewAsync("TableOrchestrator", updates);
var t2 = orchestrationClient.StartNewAsync("ClientOrchestrator", clientExport);
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
```

Comment: Even if they would depend on each other, awaiting one and then start the other would not help. This only kicks off the orchestrator, it does not wait for it to be finished.

Comment: @silent this is not correct. several of the MS examples even show the case of the orchestration results depending on each other.

Comment: Please give a link to such an example